# Unable to find vector corresponding text in ChromaDB

Tags: large-language-model, chromadb, openaiembeddings

I'm using langchain (model:text-embedding-ada-002) to convert some PDFs to embeddings with ChromaDB as follows:

```
vectorstore = Chroma.from_texts(texts=text_chunks, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectorstore.persist()
```

I used a DB browser for SQLlite to see the contents of the SQLlite file that gets generated after calling the persist() method however I can only see chunks of text in the db, I was expecting to see the corresponding vector notations too.

Does ChromaDB only store the text chunks ? Did the embeddings not get created?